# remove a follow-relation in contactlist using sql: syntax error?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying t remove a follow-relation in my database. I want with one query execute a code that removes both the one I follow, and also in the opposite direction. I've got the following code that has a syntax error:

```
//profileId is the current user and contactsProfileId which user he/she follows
$sql = "
DELETE FROM contactlists
WHERE (profileId = '$profileId AND contactsProfileId = '$contactsProfileId')
OR (profileId = '$contactsProfileId' AND contactsProfileId = '$profileId')
";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add closing ' single quote for `$profileId`.

Try this

```
$sql = "
DELETE FROM contactlists
WHERE (profileId = '$profileId' AND contactsProfileId = '$contactsProfileId')
OR (profileId = '$contactsProfileId' AND contactsProfileId = '$profileId')
";
```

Answer (score 0):

look at first `$profileId`:

```
//profileId is the current user and contactsProfileId which user he/she follows
$sql = "
DELETE FROM contactlists
WHERE (profileId = '$profileId' AND contactsProfileId = '$contactsProfileId')
OR (profileId = '$contactsProfileId' AND contactsProfileId = '$profileId')
"
```